# Eclipse device chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, tablet

My tablets do not show up in device chooser. Ive set my API levels to `android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"` .
I turned on USB debugging.I can transfer files to and from tablet. I set run config to pick device. I tried a `4.1.1` and a `4.0.3` device. Not sure what else i may be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Windows, check to see if there are any devices listed in the Device Manager without drivers. If a strangling "Android Device" is listed, manually install the Google ADB drivers for it. Those can be found in the Android SDK installer.

Comment: One tablet does have a strangling android device. I set the path to the extra google driver to update but comes up with "unable to update".

Comment: The other tablet does shows up in device manager in portable devices as EXTERNAL. not android

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: I used the path  C:\AndroidDev\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\google   but no luck.

Comment: Use the instructions here to manually pick the driver: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/ss/update-drivers-windows-7-tutorial_7.htm. It's for Windows 7, but it should still be the same steps.

Comment: Thanks,im not sure which google driver to install from the list. it gives a list of nexus types. Im not using nexus so im not sure which to install. none look like the google driver from the extras folder.

Comment: Is there an "Android ADB Interface" listed? Force it to use that one. It may warn you that the device may not be compatible, but there's a 99% chance it's the same.

Comment: What is the tablet manufacturer? Almost always, their development drivers are the same as the Google/Nexus ones, just with their specific USB identifiers included.

Comment: Yes i successfully installed the Android ADB driver.